# Passing Url to another WebView Tab and load

Tags: android, webview

I'm new to programming .
I make an app that contains 3 Tabs with viewpager. 1st tab is a list of Button with their respective link. 2nd Tab is a WebView that will load url passed from the 1st tab when the users clicked on the link. 3rd tab is my Download Manager.

This is my MainActivity:

```
 public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity{
    ActionBar mActionBar;
    Button button;
    ViewPager mPager;
    Tab tab;

    String TabFragmentB;

    public void setTabFragmentB(String t){
        TabFragmentB = t;
    }

    public String getTabFragmentB(){
        return TabFragmentB;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        // Hide Actionbar Icon
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        // Hide Actionbar Title
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        // Create Actionbar Tabs
        mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        //For ViewPager
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        //Activate FragmentManger
        FragmentManager fm= getSupportFragmentManager();

        ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener ViewPagerListener = new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position){
                super.onPageSelected(position);
                mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);//find the viewPager Potision

            }
        };

        mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPagerListener);
        // Locate the adapter class called ViewPagerAdapter.java
        ViewPagerAdapter viewpageradapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(fm);
        // Set the View Pager Adapter into ViewPager
        mPager.setAdapter(viewpageradapter);

        // Capture tab button clicks
        ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                // Pass the position on tab click to ViewPager
                mPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        };

        // Create first Tab
        tab = mActionBar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.button_home).setTabListener(tabListener);
        mActionBar.addTab(tab);

        // Create second Tab
        tab = mActionBar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.button_browse).setTabListener(tabListener);
        mActionBar.addTab(tab);

        // Create third Tab
        tab = mActionBar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.button_downloads).setTabListener(tabListener);
        mActionBar.addTab(tab);


    }


}
```

My FragmentTab1:

```
public class FragmentTab1 extends SherlockFragment implements OnClickListener{

    FragmentTab2 fTab2;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    WebView webview;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pager);
        webview = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        view.findViewById(R.id.Button01).setOnClickListener(this);
        view.findViewById(R.id.Button02).setOnClickListener(this);
        view.findViewById(R.id.Button03).setOnClickListener(this);
        view.findViewById(R.id.Button04).setOnClickListener(this);
        view.findViewById(R.id.Button05).setOnClickListener(this);


        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        setUserVisibleHint(true);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.Button01:

            String urlToBeSend = " http://google.com";
            String TabOfFragmentB = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getTabFragmentB();
            FragmentTab2 fragmentB = (FragmentTab2)getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TabOfFragmentB);
            fragmentB.b_updateText(urlToBeSend);

            Toast.makeText(getSherlockActivity(), "url to be send = " +urlToBeSend, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);

            break;
        case R.id.Button02:
            String urlToBeSend2 = " http://facebook.com";
            String TabOfFragmentB2 = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getTabFragmentB();
            FragmentTab2 fragmentB2 = (FragmentTab2)getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TabOfFragmentB2);
            fragmentB2.b_updateText(urlToBeSend2);
            Toast.makeText(getSherlockActivity(), "url to be send = " +urlToBeSend2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
            break;
        case  R.id.Button03:
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
            break;
        case  R.id.Button04:
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
            break;
        case  R.id.Button05:
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

    }


}
```

For My FragmentTab2:

```
public class FragmentTab2 extends SherlockFragment {
    private static WebView webview;
    private ProgressBar progress;

    String homeUrl="http://new3gpmovies.com/";
    private int urlIndex=0;
    String a_url;
    TextView b_received;
    ViewPager viewpager;
    public void b_updateText(String t){
        b_received.setText(t);
        a_url = t;


    }
    public FragmentTab2(){

    }


    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.webview, container, false);

        String myTag = getTag();

        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).setTabFragmentB(myTag);

        b_received = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);



        ImageView backward = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.backward);
        ImageView forward = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.forward);

        backward.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View view){
                if (webview.canGoBack()){
                    webview.goBack();
                }
            }
        });
        forward.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View view){
                if (webview.canGoForward()){
                    webview.goForward();
                }
            }
        });
        webview = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webview.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
        webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        progress = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        progress.setMax(100);

        if (a_url != null){
            webview.loadUrl(a_url);
        }else if (a_url == null){

            webview.loadUrl(homeUrl);
        }

        if (progress.getProgress() == 100){
            FragmentTab2.this.progress.setProgress(0);
        }


        return view;
    }


    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{

        @SuppressLint({ "InlinedApi", "NewApi" })
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
            boolean value = true;  

            if (url.endsWith(".3gp") || url.endsWith(".mp4")){
                Intent downloadIntent = new Intent("com.nanoidea.download.services.IDownloadService");
                downloadIntent.putExtra(MyIntents.TYPE, MyIntents.Types.ADD);
                downloadIntent.putExtra(MyIntents.URL, Utils.url[urlIndex]);
                getActivity().startService(downloadIntent);

                urlIndex++;
                if (urlIndex >= Utils.url.length) {
                    urlIndex = 0;
                }

                value=false;

            }
            if(value){
                view.loadUrl(url);
            }

            return value;  
        }
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl){

            webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/failedPage.html");
        }
    }


    public String getFileName(String url) {  
        String filenameWithoutExtension = ""; 
        if (url.endsWith("3gp")){

            filenameWithoutExtension = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()  
                    + ".3gp"); 
        }else if  (url.endsWith(".mp4")){

            filenameWithoutExtension = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()
                    + ".mp4"); 
        }
        return filenameWithoutExtension;  
    }  

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        setUserVisibleHint(true);

    }   
    private class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient{

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress){
            FragmentTab2.this.setValue(newProgress);
            super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
        }

    }
    public void setValue(int progress){
        this.progress.setProgress(progress);


    }
    public static boolean canGoBack(){
        return webview.canGoBack();
    }
    public static void goBack(){
        webview.goBack();
    }

}
```

**Question:**

Why when i click on the link from the 1st tab  the second tab doesn't change? even if the 2nd tab received the string url from the 1st tab? any idea? Please guide me.

Comment: is there any error message?

Comment: No error at all. But the the fragment2 don't reload when a new url received.

Comment: I fixed the problem.. i just put in the fragment2 public void b_updateText(String t){
        b_received.setText(t);
        webview.loadUrl(t);